# is it possible to implement flip as a Scala function (and not a method)

Tags: scala

As a part of learning Scala I try to implement Haskell's *flip* function (a function with signature *(A => B => C) => (B => A => C)*) in Scala - and implement it as a function (using *val*) and not as a method (using *def*).

I can implement it as a method, for instance this way:

```
def flip[A, B, C](f: (A, B) => C):((B, A) => C) = (b: B, a: A) => f(a, b)
val minus = (a: Int, b: Int) => a - b
val f = flip(minus)
println(f(3, 5))
```

However, when I try to implement it as a function, it does not work:

```
val flip = (f: ((Any, Any) => Any)) => ((a: Any, b: Any) => f(b, a))
val minus = (a: Int, b: Int) => a - b
val f = flip(minus)
println(f(3, 5))
```

When I try to compile this code, it fails with this message:

```
Error:(8, 18) type mismatch;
found   : (Int, Int) => Int
required: (Any, Any) => Any
val f = flip(minus)
```

I understand why it fails: I try to pass *(Int, Int) => Int* where *(Any, Any) => Any* is expected. However, I don't know how to fix this problem. Is it possible at all?

Comment: `def something` might not be a function, but it returns a function, what is wrong with that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scala doesn't support polymorphic functions, unlike methods which are. This is due to the first class value nature of functions, which are simply instances of the `FunctioN` traits. These functions are classes, and they need the types to be bound at declaration site.

If we took the `flip` method and tried to eta expand it to a function, we'd see:

```
val flipFn = flip _
```

We'd get back in return a value of type:

```
((Nothing, Nothing) => Nothing) => (Nothing, Nothing) => Nothing
```

Due to the fact that none of the types were bound, hence the compiler resorts to the buttom type `Nothing`.

However, not all hope is lost. There is a library called [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) which does allow us to define polymorphic functions via `PolyN`.

We can implement flip like this:

```
import shapeless.Poly1

object flip extends Poly1 {
  implicit def genericCase[A, B, C] = at[(A, B) => C](f => (b: B, a: A) => f(a, b))
}
```

`flip` is no different from the `FunctionN` trait, it defines an `apply` method which will be called.

We use it like this:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val minus = (a: Int, b: Int) => a - b
  val f = flip(minus)
  println(f(3, 5))
}
```

Yielding:

```
2
```

This would also work for `String`:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val stringConcat = (a: String, b: String) => a + b
  val f = flip(stringConcat)
  println(f("hello", "world"))
}
```

Yielding:

```
worldhello
```